# channel.send is not a function? (Discord.JS)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Normally I wouldn't ask for help, but I've tried almost everything and I'm stumped. Here is my code,

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const timedResponses = ["Test"]

const token = '';


client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('the doctor is ready');
        client.user.setActivity('medical documentaries', { type: 'WATCHING'}).catch(console.error);
        const channel = client.channels.fetch('691070971251130520')
        setInterval(() => {
        const response = timedResponses [Math.floor(Math.random()*timedResponses .length)];
        channel.send(response).then().catch(console.error);
    }, 5000);
});
client.login(token);
```

The code seems to be working fine on my other bots, but for some reason it refuses to work on this one.

Edit: I tried to add console.log(channel) but I got an error. "Channel" is not defined.

Comment: `working fine on my other bots` please clarify

Comment: The [documentation for the latest version](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) doesn't mention `.send()` at all - if you check your `package.json` for this project and another one that works, which version of `discord.js` do they use?

Comment: Nevermind, looks like some other classes extending `Channel` do have it. Could you please `console.log(channel)` and see what it gives out? You can edit your question to include details.

Comment: Try changing the `const channel` to something else like `const msgChannel`.

Answer (score 3):

ChannelManager#fetch returns a `Promise` [Check the return type in the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch)

You could fix your issue by using `async / await`

```js
client.once("ready", async () => {
  // Fetch the channel
  const channel = await client.channels.fetch("691070971251130520")
  // Note that it's possible the channel couldn't be found
  if (!channel) {
    return console.log("could not find channel")
  }

  channel.send("Your message")
})
```

I am assuming you copied the ID manually from a text based channel, if this ID is dynamic you should check if the channel is a text channel

```js
const { TextChannel } = require("discord.js")

if (channel instanceof TextChannel) {
  // Safe to send in here
}
```